# xml.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode Giving EOF Error _GOLang

Tags: html, xml, go

I'm trying to Decode XML from body  a html response.

=>I saved this response body as string to a Variable and successfully decoded Using      xml.Unmarshal  Function .Code for that :

```
    err = xml.Unmarshal([]byte(outs), &v)
       if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error is here: %v", err)
    return
                       }
```

So I think problem is NOT with actual Content of Response body.

Now My Actual Code :

```
req1, err := http.NewRequest("GET", concat([]string{domain, defects_link}), nil)
error_handler(err)
req1.Close = true //I tried with and without this line 

resp1, err := client.Do(req1)
error_handler(err)

fmt.Printf("\n %s \n", resp1.Status)

defer resp1.Body.Close()//I tried with and without this line
conts1, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp1.Body)
error_handler(err)
fmt.Println("Response Body is Here :", string(conts1))//Contents are Printed Here
```

Response is printed  in last line of above code.But below code is giving "Error :EOF"

```
    if err := xml.NewDecoder(resp1.Body).Decode(&v); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error is : %v", err)

    return
}
```

What is wrong in my code.Kindly Help

Comment: Do you Decode after print ioutil.ReadAll or print ioutil.ReadAll just a test?

Comment: ioutil.ReadAll  was there in actual code,and now I got that is reason why my code was not working, from VonC's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you already read the [`Body io.ReadCloser`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) once (with `conts1, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp1.Body)`), you cannot ask another function to read it again (or you will get the `EOF` error message).

> I saved this response body as string to a Variable and successfully decoded Using xml.Unmarshal Function.

That seems the easiest approach to use the body content multiple times.