# invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference after first loop iteration

Tags: http, pointers, go, scope

When I return (A map slice) from `GetCompanyFilingListRes` and print the output my code runs fine for one iteration. But on the second iteration I get a `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`.

```
package main

import (
    "data/edgar"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    url := "calltomylocalserver.com/page.html"
    res, _ := http.Get(url)
    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        // GetCompanyFilingListRes comsumes res.Body 
        // before returning a slice of maps
        m := edgar.GetCompanyFilingListRes(res)
        fmt.Println(m)
    }
}
```

I'm sure this is something quite simple I'm missing but I don't why `res` doesn't seem to be accessible after the first iteration. Is the GC removing it from memory? How would I stop this happening? Thanks.

Edit:

I think my mistake with this question was not including the fact that GetCompanyFilingListRes consumes the `res.Body`. And as [leaf bebop mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056586/5319281) it can only be consumed once.

There's a related answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879587/xml-newdecoderresp-body-decode-giving-eof-error-golang).

Comment: What does `edgar.GetCompanyFilingListRes` do? Very likely, the problem is there. Please post a [**complete** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You're gonna want to check the error. `res, err := http.Get(url) if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }`

Comment: @phihag It scrapes a webpage and as I mentioned it returns a map slice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems very likely to be because `res` is a `Response` and `Response.Body` is a `ReadCloser` which can only be consumed once.

If you want to re-use the body, read it into a buffer (like []byte or a string) using `ioutil.ReadAll`. If you want extra data from `res`, use a struct to wrap it.

If your use case auctually use different responses (which make more sense to me), move the `http.Get` into the loop. (Warning: fetch an url 1e5 times can cause trouble).